# Service Fabric: View contents of Reliable Dictionary while local debugging

Tags: local, azure-service-fabric, reliable-dictionary

Is there a way to view the contents of a reliable dictionary while local debugging. I can't find any property which gives me the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't inspect a property, but you could call [CreateEnumerableAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.data.collections.ireliabledictionary-2.createenumerableasync) to get an async enumerable.

Sample:

```
using (var tran = this.stateManager.CreateTransaction())
{
    var asyncEnumerable = await yourDictionary.CreateEnumerableAsync(tran);
    var asyncEnumerator = asyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator();
    
    while (await asyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync(cancelationToken))
    {
        log.Debug(asyncEnumerator.Current);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there might be anything which I am not aware of.  Will loop through and check the elements. Thanks !!!